# Does this code qualify as a Quine in Java?

Tags: java, theory, quine

Here's the code. It basically reads from the original code file and prints onto the terminal.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Quine
{
    static void Quine() throws IOException
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Quine.java");        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s = "";
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
           System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Practically, it works just fine, producing the same exact code as output. But by definition, does it qualify as a quine? Considering I'm still passing a file to it as a parameter. Despite it being a programmer-specified and not a user-entered input, is it still considered an input?

Comment: it would only print the code of the class Quine anyways (not the source actually needed to make it runnable)... Where is your main method?

Comment: additionally it would not qualify as a quine because the whole conept here depends on the fact the the source is located at "C:\Quine.java". Run it from somewhere else and it is broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not considered a valid **quine**, you have to avoid any I/O operation.

Opening the source code to print it out it's the first cheat to avoid!

Comment: Here is an example of a Quine: http://blogs.adobe.com/charles/2011/01/my-adventure-writing-my-first-quine-in-java.html

Comment: Thanks!
So basically, the code has to contain the code. That's...messed up.

Answer (score 2):

It would only print the code of the class Quine anyways (not the source actually needed to make it runnable - the main method). So, no it is not a Quine.

> A [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) is a non-empty computer program which takes no input and
>   produces a copy of its own source code as its only output.